# python Postgresql: Ignoring the last column from csv file

Tags: python, postgresql

I have problem with importing a CSV file. I am using postgresql's COPY FROM command to copy a CSV file into a 2-column table.

I have a CSV file in the following format;

```
"1";"A"
"2";"B"
"3";"C";"CAD450"
"4";"D";"ABX123"
```

I want to import all these lines of the CSV file into the table but I want to skip any extra added columns.

Currently I am skipping any lines that contain extra columns, for example here columns `"1";"C";"CAD450"` and `"1";"D";"ABX123"` are skipped  and I am importing only the first two columns. But I want to copy all these four lines into my table. So is there any way where I can ignore the last column and copy all the four lines into my table, like this

```
"1";"A"
"1";"B"
"1";"C"
"1";"D"
```

Comment: Could you please provide some example code how you import the CSV today? You probably need to parse each line of the CSV and pipe it into postgres with the superfluous columns removed.

Comment: I use the following code to import data from csv file.                                                                    f = open(path, 'r')

p = Popen(command, shell=True,stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE, env=env)
 
query = """
 field1, field2) 
 FROM STDIN
 WITH DELIMITER ';' CSV QUOTE '"';
 """
p.stdin.write(query.encode('ascii'))

for line in f:
 
 here i did some checking , 




p.stdin.write(line.encode('UTF-8'))

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code with proper formatting. In the comment as it is now, this is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("file.csv","r") as f:
    t=[line.strip().split(";")[:2] for line in f]
```

Answer (score 2):

Preprocess the file with awk to strip the extra columns:

```
awk -F';' '{print $1 ";" $2 }' > new_file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Piping it through `cut` or `awk` (as suggested above) is easier than using python/psycopg.

`cat csv_file.csv | cut -d';' -f1,2 | psql -u USER  DATABASE -c "COPY table FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER ';';"`

Answer (score 1):

Myriad ways to handle the problem.
I'd probably do something like this:

```
import csv
import psycopg2
dr = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv','rb'), 
                    delimiter=';',
                    quotechar='"',
                    fieldnames=['col1','col2']) # need not specify other cols
CONNSTR = """
  host=127.0.0.1 
  dbname=mydb
  user=me
  password=pw
  port=5432"""
cxn = psycopg2.connect(CONNSTR)
cur = cxn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE from_csv (
               id serial NOT NULL,
               col1 character varying,
               col2 character varying,
               CONSTRAINT from_csv_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id));""")
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO from_csv (col1,col2) 
                   VALUES (%(col1)s,%(col2)s);""", dr)
cxn.commit()
```